# MySQL sports database

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, relational-database

I am trying to make a sports database, but I am new to SQL.

I have table of goals, assists, etc. Each goal has a time, playerid and matchid to know who and when scored it. The same for assists and others.

Then, I have a table with all players. There are their names, ids, numbers etc.

I want to ask, if this is a good concept of data division between tables, if I want to make query for one player, how many goals he scored, assists passed etc. for all time, then can be filtered by season, match etc.

I can quite imagine how to do this with the foreign keys.

But will it be fast enough if i will have 100 000 goals and more in the goals table, then the same for assists and others, maybe even milion of records?

Another thing is, would I'll be able to sort players by this counted number of goals for example, if I will query all the players?

So I will generate a new table on website with all players and their alltime stats by individually counting goals, assists... for each one, and then sort them by goals and other things?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Seems alright to me.

Comment: "Will it be fast enough" is actually not that hard to answer. Make a test data fabricator, load up your database with *millions* of records, and see how your queries perform. See how many queries per second you can run with X million records and look for where performance drops off. With a modern CPU and an NVMe drive the answer might be kind of ridiculous and hopefully well beyond your intended use case.

Comment: Don't forget to apply all the usual database optimization tricks, especially tuning your server properly and indexing all your relational data where relevant. Little fixes like that can increase performance dramatically, or hold it back if not observed.

Comment: *I have table of goals, assists, etc. Each goal has a time, playerid and matchid to know who and when scored it. The same for assists and others.* Looks like one entity "action".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, it looks fine for what do you want to achieve. As for your seconds question, I assume you want to sort the players already in the database. To achieve this, MySQL has a command called  ORDER BY. Here is what it would look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM PLAYERS
ORDER BY GOALS
```

It will sort in ascending order by default. If you want to sort by descending order, add DESC after GOALS.
For more details, check this tutorial: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/